# jquery: check if string exist in element, return boolean

Tags: jquery

Assuming I have this:

`<div id="elementId">bla bla bla some text bla bla</div>`

I want to check if this div text contains 'some text', then return true, otherwise return false, how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean if it contains the string "some text" or just some text ?

Comment: @Aerus There are quotes around the words "some text" in the question.

Comment: @Jacob ok, i was confused since your answer checks for "bla" instead of "some text"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
var isContains = $('#elementId').text().indexOf('some text') > -1;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and check the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see if it matched anything, like this:

```
return $("#elementId:contains('some text')").length > 0;
```

Comment: @Nick Why use this when you can use native JS methods?

Comment: @Jacob - I don't follow, since when are `$()` and `.text()` native JS methods?  `:contains()` calls the same thing underneath.

Comment: @Jacob - just something to keep in mind, `.innerText` won't work in Firefox :) http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04

Comment: @Nick Thanks for that. I never really use `.innerText` anyway, so yeah jQuery helps there for sure. As much as I love jQuery, sometimes I feel that it overlaps onto features that should be left alone. This kind of overlapping is what IMO contributes to people thinking that jQuery is a language, when really it's just a framework.

Answer (score 3):

I used the same way of the buddy above...:

`if($('#div_searched').text().indexOf('bla') != -1)`

This will return true when it found the word bla on div_searched

Answer (score 1):

```
let myNode = document.getElementById("elementId")
const Value = myNode.textContent || myNode.innerText
const txtExist = Boolean(Value.replace(/\s/g, ""));
```

Note:
innerText does work in IE, also
textContent is not supported in IE8 and older

Answer (score 0):

I think this should also work.

```
return $("#elementId:contains('some text')").length ? true : false;
```

It should return true if length greater than 0, otherwise it will return false.